# Is it possible to loop a UIScrollView/UIPageControl?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

Was wondering if it's possible to have a a pagecontrol/scrollview to loop.

Example: When swiping from the last page to the right, it will go to the first page. Or swiping from the first page to the left, it will go to the last page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [iCarousel control](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) for that. With `iCarouselTypeLinear`  it looks pretty much like a paged scrollview.

Implement the delegate method `- (BOOL)carouselShouldWrap:(iCarousel *)carousel;` to return YES.